# jQuery Popup Overlay not displaying when using a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any idea why this doesn't work when calling it as a class? I'm trying to make a popup of file contents for each entry in a database. Slightly irrelevant to this, but thought I'd add to clarify the intent.

```
<div id="myModal">Filename</div>

  <!-- Add an optional button to open the popup -->
  <button class="my_popup_open">Open popup</button>

  <!-- Add content to the popup -->
  <div id="my_popup">

    <p class="my_popup">"$GPGGA,172247.103,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4F
$GPGGA,172257.000,3027.4646,N,09008.6986,W,1,13,0.81,21.2,M,-26.0,M,,*6F
$GPGGA,172307.000,3027.4661,N,09008.6977,W,1,14,0.71,23.3,M,-26.0,M,,*6B
$GPGGA,172317.000,3027.4681,N,09008.6962,W,1,14,0.71,23.9,M,-26.0,M,,*6A
$GPGGA,172327.000,3027.4683,N,09008.6927,W,1,14,0.72,23.5,M,-26.0,M,,*65
$GPGGA,172337.000,3027.4684,N,09008.6880,W,1,14,0.71,23.3,M,-26.0,M,,*6A
$GPGGA,172347.000,3027.4679,N,09008.6880,W,1,17,0.62,23.4,M,-26.0,M,,*69
$GPGGA,172357.000,3027.4679,N,09008.6880,W,1,17,0.62,23.4,M,-26.0,M,,*68
$GPGGA,172407.000,3027.4679,N,09008.6881,W,1,18,0.60,23.3,M,-26.0,M,,*61
$GPGGA,172417.000,3027.4678,N,09008.6881,W,1,19,0.58,23.3,M,-26.0,M,,*6B
$GPGGA,172427.000,3027.4675,N,09008.6899,W,1,19,0.57,23.2,M,-26.0,M,,*62
$GPGGA,172437.000,3027.4688,N,09008.6963,W,1,19,0.57,21.7,M,-26.0,M,,*62
$GPGGA,172447.000,3027.4690,N,09008.6973,W,1,18,0.59,20.3,M,-26.0,M,,*67
$GPGGA,172507.000,3027.4695,N,09008.6981,W,2,18,0.59,17.3,M,-26.0,M,0000,0000*6D
$GPGGA,172517.000,3027.4697,N,09008.6981,W,2,18,0.59,15.5,M,-26.0,M,0000,0000*6A
$GPGGA,172527.000,3027.4700,N,09008.6980,W,2,18,0.59,14.1,M,-26.0,M,0000,0000*62
"</p>


  </div>








  <!-- Include jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include jQuery Popup Overlay -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.10/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>



  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Initialize the plugin
      $('.my_popup').popup();

    });
  </script>
```

If I change:

```
$('.my_popup').popup();
```

To:

```
   <p id="my_popup">

   and


$('#my_popup').popup();
```

It works fine. But that won't allow me to replicate the setup on a single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are using explicitly references the node's `id` to identify the open/close button element. From its [source code](https://github.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/blob/gh-pages/jquery.popupoverlay.js#L193):

```
var openelement = (options.openelement) ? options.openelement : ('.' + el.id + opensuffix);
```

You can get around that by providing your own `openelement`, like follows:

```
$('.my_popup').popup({ openelement: ".my_popup_open" });
```

Comment: Sorry, was in the middle of specifying that I am changing the element to have the id="my_popup' as well..which allows it to work for one instance. I can't understand why it doesn't work with the class selector though?